# Inbound Email handler and to get only latest mail

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, inboundservices

I am writing an `Inbound Email Apex Handler`.

My situation is that whenever we get a reply from a client through email to salesforce, I only want to parse through the mail that was sent now and not the complete email thread.

Any idea, how I can do that?

@AjayGupta , I tried this string and it is not working  -

> Checking third timeOn Fri, Aug 21, 2015 at 12:03 AM, kaushik ray wrote:> Checking again.>> On Thu, Aug 20, 2015 at 11:59 PM, kaushik ray > wrote:>>> Hi Support,>>>> Thanks for this.>>>> I had a very good experience using the product. I was able to use it with>> out any issues.>>>> Thanks,>> Ray>>>> On Thu, Aug 20, 2015 at 11:55 PM, Salesforce Developer <>> abc@gmail.com> wrote:>>>>> Hello,>>>>>> How are you. I hope you are doing good.>>>>>> I just wanted to get a feedback about your past one month of usage.>>>>>> Do let me know how I can help.>>>>>> Thanks,>>> Support>>>>>>>>> _____________________________________________________________________>>> Powered by salesforce.com>>> http://www.salesforce.com/>>>>>>>>>

**Update 2**

I tried this mail, but still was not able to get correct result

> Mail 2 :: Hello you still like my product.!!!
>   Thanks def
>   On Sun, Aug 23, 2015 at 1:16 AM, kaushik ray 
>   wrote:Hello nice meeting you again. Mail 1Thanks,abcThanks,Ray

Answer (score 3):

I have written a custom logic to solve this problem for you(@ray) by spliting the response into parts using regular expression `\\w{2} \\w{3}, \\w{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4} at \\d{1,2}:\\d{2} [PA]M, .*:`, please check and try to execute this in your sandbox to test it:

```
String parseResponse(String message){
    List<String> splitResult = message.split('\\w{2} \\w{3}, \\w{3} \\d{2}, \\d{4} at \\d{1,2}:\\d{2} [PA]M, .*:');
    if(splitResult.size()>=2){
        return splitResult[0];
    }
   return message;
}
```

Call this method and pass the `email.plainTextBody` as parameter to `parseResponse()` private method as declared above in your `Inbound Email Apex Class` and received response will contain only current message not trailed complete email.

Let me know in case of any other help!!

Comment: Can you also explain how this is working the split line. That will be helpful

Comment: I tried this but it is still taking the complete thread of mail. I tried to reply from my gmail

Comment: I have also tested it using gmail email account, it is working fine , could you please paste content of email thread?

Comment: I tried this - 

second mail

On Thu, Aug 20, 2015 at 4:27 PM, kaushik ray <abc@gmail.com>
wrote:

> tesing mail helli
>

Comment: it gave me the initial mail as well to which i replied

Comment: Can line breask cause any issue?

Comment: No line break does not cause any issue.

Comment: I added one edit to initial question with mail text that is not working. Can you help me with same

Comment: I have modified the code, request to check this now and let me know if still having any issue.

Comment: I was able to make it work by removing all line breaks and then making the text pass through your code. If there are line breaks then, it fails..!! Still not sure about the working of you code, but it has been a great help from you